# How can I change the colour of C/C++ data member references in VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to change the colour of the variable inside a struct in C. Specifically the `(*stack_a)->sorted_pos` member (please see attached picture). I'd like to make the pink-ish colour of such variables orange instead.

[(picture example of struct variable to be changed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AluZ6.png)

Or a more brief example:

```c
typedef struct { int bar; } Foo;
int baz(Foo* foo) {
   return foo->bar; // <- I want to change `bar` here
}
```

I have gone through the .json file for my theme (Spaceduck), and tried changing many of the variables in there to find the right one, but to no success. I also tried googling to find the name of that specific variable (I would guessing it would be something like keyword.struct.variable, or something similar), but could not find it.

Where can I find this information, or what is variable for the text called?

Comment: You can do this by modifying semantic highlighting https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide ... there are several tutorials on "vscode semantic highlighting" ... have a look at this.


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vthJRp8jPkw

Comment: find the TextMate Scope of the purple text and customize the scope color

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) to get info about colour scopes.

Without any C language support extensions other than [the basic builtin one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/cpp), then you would use the `variable.other.member.c` and `variable.other.property.cpp` TextMate scopes. Ex. (put this in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson))

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[name of your selected theme goes here]": { // optionally remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "variable.other.member.c",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                },
            },
        ].
    },
},
```

With the Microsoft C/C++ extension, you would need to use the `variable.other.property.c` and `variable.other.property.c` TextMate scopes instead, which (unfortunately?) applies to both member variable references and also their declarations. Or you could handle both cases by using `"scope": "variable.other.member.c, variable.other.property.c, variable.other.property.cpp",`. The Microsoft C/C++ extension also provides [semantic highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide), so you could also write something like this in your settings.json to get a similar effect:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[name of your selected theme goes here]": { // optionally remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
        "rules": {
            "property:c": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
            },
            "property:cpp": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
            },
        },
    },
},
```